# Spark Job aborted due to stage failure: java.lang.NullPointerException when loading xml files using spark-xml

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Thanks everyone for your help in advance! I am very new to Spark and have been using Databricks (Runtime Version 5.0, includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11).

I have been trying to load some XML files using spark-xml (2.11.0.5.0), and encountering the following sparkException:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 5 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 
5.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 17, 10.106.234.32, executor 0): 
java.lang.NullPointerException

at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps$.apply$extension(StringOps.scala:37)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRecordReader.readUntilStartElement(XmlInputFormat.scala:156)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRecordReader.next(XmlInputFormat.scala:131)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRecordReader.nextKeyValue(XmlInputFormat.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:124)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:459)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1401)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:465)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It is weird that there was no issue loading the files the day before using exact same configs of the cluster:

- Databricks runtime version: 5.0 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.0, Scala 2.11)
- Driver and worker type: i3.xlarge - 30.5 GB Memory, 4 Cores, 1 DBU

Each of the uncompressed XML files range from 70M to 130M in size and there are 8 of them. I hope to load them into one dataset.

I got the data as follows and uploaded them to Databricks:

```
wget ftp://ftp.nlm.nih.gov/nlmdata/sample/medline/*.gz
gunzip *.gz
```

Here is the code:

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{Text, LongWritable}


def loadMedline(spark: SparkSession, path: String) = {
  import spark.implicits._

  /* conf: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration = Configuration: 
   * core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, 
   * mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, 
   * hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml
   */

  @transient val conf = new Configuration()
  conf.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, "<MedlineCitation>")
  conf.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, "</MedlineCitation>")

  /* sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext */
  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  /* records: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)] = 
   * dbfs:/FileStore/tables/ch7_medline/ NewHadoopRDD[0] at newAPIHadoopFile at command-2335143412865645:1
   */

  val records = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[XmlInputFormat],
    classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text])

  /* returns: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string] */
  records.map(line => line._2.toString).toDS()
}

/* medlineRaw: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string] */
val medlineRaw = loadMedline(spark, "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/ch7_medline/")

medlineRaw.count()   // <--- got the error here
```

Again thank you very much! Looked around for quite a while but still couldn't get it working.

Comment: May I suggest that, to help us out, you provide types for each of the variables and methods? You can do that easily in an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA by clicking the identifier, then clicking the light bulb that shows up.

Comment: Thank you @Phasmid! I have added the types in the comments. Would those suffice?

Comment: Well, you added the types in a curious (but satisfactory for these purposes) way. The null pointer exception you're getting appears to be when trying to get a character from a String which is null. I am suspicious of your lambda "line => line._2.toString." _2 refers to a (Hadoop) Text object. Are you sure that toString is valid for all possible Text objects? Could it be that an end-of-data condition might return null? Anyway, my recommendation is to look more carefully at results returned by that lambda. You could try filtering out null values, for instance.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you sooooo much @Phasmid !!